# Login redirecting to Login Page

Tags: magento-1.9.2

Please help! I have created a custom login form at https://cashino.kellyseye.com/ using the following code:

```
<div class="top-content-text cf m-all t-1of2 d-1of2 first">
<h3>Store Login</h3>
<div class="block block-login"><form 
action="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/customer/account/loginPost/" 
method="post">
<div class="block-content"><input id="mini-login" class="input-text" 
spellcheck="false" type="email" placeholder="Email:" name="login[username]" 
/> <input id="mini-password" class="input-text" type="password" 
placeholder="Password:" name="login[password]" /> <input type="hidden" 
value="&lt;?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')-&gt;getFormKey() ? 
&gt;" name="form_key" />
<div class="actions"><button class="button" type="submit"> <span> 
<span>Login</span> </span> </button></div>
</div>
</form></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is, when I enter my email and password, I am redirected to the login page and NOT logged in. Does anyone know why?

I have used the same code at https://beaconbingo.kellyseye.com/ and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a issue in your `formkey`, It should generate a `key` something like `value="74LCjTfVZawT"` and not like `value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>"`

   Try to remove `<input value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" name="form_key" type="hidden">` then add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>` just after the `<form ..>` tag.
2. Check your login controller what you return on submit with the different cases.

   The controller path : `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php::loginPostAction()`

#### Important : Don't update this controller direclty, if you have to add some updates, you must rewrite it in `local`, `app/code/local` instead of `core`, `app/code/core`.